# Не заходит в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Пишет "Неизвестная Ошибка. Детали см. в файле ActivityLog.xml". Внутри файла html код и никакого ответа. Пытался установить новый VS но при установке пишет что нельзя установить в непустом каталоге.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать Repair в инсталлере

Comment: А как это сделать? Если можете покажите на скриншоте.

Comment: Visual Studio Installer работает? Там кроме Modify и Launch есть Repair

Comment: Нет там такого, там есть только установить при скачивании и Скачать все и установить. О том что вы писали нет вообще. Попробую удалить все и переустановить.

Comment: Я понял о чем вы говорите, но это не помогло

Comment: Это сработало, удаление всех предыдущих версий решило проблему